# Milliseconds to Date

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to convert `1465768996460.76245` to `Date`. I use 
http://www.ruddwire.com/handy-code/date-to-millisecond-calculators/#.V2mI-JN97UI to check if the value is right.

Above value should print something like "Sun Jun 12 2016 22:03:16 GMT+0000" which it doesn't.

It gets the time off by approx 20 min and yy-mm-dd is way off.

Using the code

```
print(NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:NSTimeInterval(1465768996460.76245))))
```

This prints `48449-05-15 22:34:20 +0000`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` expects a value in seconds and the reference date is actually 1 January 2001.

Your value seems to be the number of miliseconds after the UNIX epoch. You should use the `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970` constructor instead. Don't forget to divide the number by 1000 to make it to seconds.

```
let seconds: Double = 1465768996460.76245 / 1000
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: seconds)

print(date) //2016-06-12 22:03:16 +0000
```

Comment: When I do the same I get 2047-06-13 22:03:16 +0000

Comment: You get 2047 if you use the "timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate" constructor. I've tested this same code and I get the correct date. Are you sure that you are using the "timeIntervalSince1970" constructor?